# Remove "Click here to add new item" from RadGridView through property in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How to Remove "Click here to add new item" option from RadGridView through property in WPF?

```
 <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="AttachmentGridView" Margin="10" 
                        ColumnWidth="auto" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                        GroupPanelForeground="#FF0081A7"
                        GroupPanelBackground="#FFF3F3F3"
                        BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC" 
                        ColumnBackground="#AACCCCCC" 
                        GridLinesVisibility="Both" 
                        telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" 
                        DataLoadMode="Asynchronous"
                        NewRowPosition="Top"
                        Foreground="#FF0081A7" 
                        AlternateRowBackground="#FFF3F3F3" 
                        IsFilteringAllowed="False"
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                        CanUserInsertRows="False" 
                        AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" 
                        FontFamily="Trebuchet MS"
                        FontSize="12" 
                        ShowGroupPanel="False" >

                        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                             <telerik:GridViewColumn Header="Name " IsCustomSortingEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="150"/>
                             </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                         </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the property:

```
NewRowPosition="None"
```

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/rows/adding-rows

Answer (score 0):

You can hide "Click here to add new row" by using the designer or programmatically.

If you want to use the designer, select RadGridView and in the Properties panel, navigate to the MasterGridViewTemplate property, then click the "+" sign to open a list of its subproperties and set the AllowAddNewRow property to false.

To do this programmatically, paste the following code snippet into the `Form_Load`event handler:

```
radGridView1.MasterGridViewTemplate.AllowAddNewRow = false;
```

Comment: MasterGridViewTemplate is for Winforms not WPF (http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/api/html/t_telerik_wincontrols_ui_mastergridviewtemplate.htm)